# React wont send req.user to API endpoint, browser returns object as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am using PassportJS authentication for my React app. The login seems to be working correctly when I use the browser to authenticate and login, `GET` and `POST` data to endpoints. However, when I try to retrieve data from the API within the react component, I get a 500 error from the server saying `req.user` is `undefined`

The post is triggered inside my component using `fetch()`

```
   _getItems(){
     fetch('/api/items').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
     }).then(function(j) {
        console.log(j);
     });
   }
```

Which then returns a 500, if i then simply go to the endpoint in the browser `localhost/api/items` I see the expected response without error.

Any ideas what is going on, and why React doesnt seem to be sending the authenticated request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the fetch() call needs to explicitly be given access to the session cookies **`{credentials: 'same-origin'}`**.

```
 _getItems(){
     fetch('/api/items', {credentials: 'same-origin'}).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
     }).then(function(j) {
        console.log(j);
     });
   }
```

Thanks [@robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747941/accessing-passports-req-user-within-react-es6-api-call-returns-req-user-as-u)!